# How can I disable mat-form-field or mat-autocomplete if list is empty?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to disable `mat-form-field` and/or mat-autocomplete if source list is empty. I've tried `disable="true"` (disable=list.empty) on `mat-form-field` and doesnt work.

Here's stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbdkokmnelo?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.html

What if the fruits list was empty?

I'm looking for something like disabled `mat-select`...

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rkdgkaerxdk?file=app%2Fselect-disabled-example.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable MatChipList just write [disabled]="true" in `mat-chip-list` tag. Now the user can not remove chips anymore.

If you want to disable the input field, just write [disabled]="true" in the `input` tag.

Of course you can use any condition instead of `true`